# How to draw this flowchart diagram in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, packages

[image]How to draw the picture in latex (just leave to background colours if difficult to code)[tikzpicture would be great]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                                  
\geometry{landscape}                            
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\title{Brief Article}

\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point, with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm and 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
            > = {Triangle[fill=gray, angle=60:2pt 3]},
     L/.style = {font=\sffamily\bfseries},
     S/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, font=\sffamily\bfseries,
                 text width=4.4em, minimum height=11mm, align=center,
                 inner xsep=2pt,
                 signal from=west, signal to=east,
                 on chain}
                        ]
\node (s1) [S=teal]   {Collection};
\node (s2) [S=blue]   {Examination};
\node (s3) [S=purple] {Analysis};
\node (s4) [S=green]  {Reporting};
%
\path[draw=gray, line width=1mm, rounded corners, ->] 
      (s4.south) -- ++ (0,-0.8) -| (s1);
%%
\node (l1) [L,below=of s1] {Media};
\node (l2) [L,below=of s2] {Data};
\node (l3) [L,below=of s3] {Information};
\node (l4) [L,below=of s4] {evidence};
%
\path[draw=gray, line width=1mm]
      (l1) edge[->] (l2) (l2) edge[->] (l3) (l3) edge[->] (l4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, met my requirement

Answer (score 3):

OK, not the sharpest knife, but I tried to shade the arrow below... I'll give it a try while looking for a better solution.
[image: signal nodes with shading arrow]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning,arrows.meta,calc}

\tikzset{sign/.style={
            draw=#1,
            line width=2pt,
            fill=#1!50,
            minimum height=2cm,
            minimum width=4cm,
            text width=1.5cm,
            inner xsep=8pt,
            signal,
            signal from=west ,
            signal to=east,
            font=\sffamily\large,
            align=center
            },
        legend/.style={
            font=\sffamily\large,
            below=1.5cm of #1
            },
        arr2/.style={
            line width=4.1pt,
            -{Stealth[scale=.75]}
            },
        arr/.style={
            line width=2pt,
            -{Stealth[scale=.75]}
            }
            }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[sign=violet] (Col) {Collection};
        \node[sign=blue,right= 5pt of Col] (Exam) {Examination};
        \node[sign=red,right= 5pt of Exam] (An) {Analysis};
        \node[sign=olive,right= 5pt of An] (Report) {Reporting};
        
        \draw[line width=4.1pt,rounded corners=5pt,olive] (Report.south) |-++ (-0.2,-1) coordinate(aux);
        \path[shade, shading=axis, right color=olive, left color=red] ($(aux)+(0.05,2pt)$) rectangle ($(An|-aux)+(0,-2pt)$);
        \path[shade, right color=red, left color=blue] ($(An|-aux)+(0,2pt)$) rectangle ($(Exam|-aux)+(0,-2pt)$);
        \path[shade, right color=blue, left color=violet] ($(Exam|-aux)+(0,2pt)$) rectangle ($(Col|-aux)+(0.3,-2pt)$);
        \draw[rounded corners=5pt,violet,arr2] ($(Col|-aux)+(0.3,0)$) -| (Col.south);
        
        
        \node [legend=Col] (A) {Media};
        \node [legend=Exam] (B) {Data};
        \node [legend=An] (C) {Information};
        \node [legend=Report] (D) {Evidence};
        
        \draw[arr] (A) -- (B);
        \draw[arr] (B) -- (C);
        \draw[arr] (C) -- (D); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```